# How to define dependency links in setup.py, for installing modules which are not present in PyPI

Tags: python, dependencies, setup.py

I have a requirement (icdiff) for my module newprog and this module is present only on github, its not on PyPi, so I am writing the urls in dependency_links[],

```
dependency_links=["https://github.com/vnitinv/icdiff/blob/master/icdiff.py"],
install_requires=['icdiff']
```

But this is not working for me.It is giving

```
Downloading/unpacking icdiff (from newprog==0.1)
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement icdiff (from
newprog==0.1)
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for icdiff (from newprog==0.1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061610/pip-install-dependency-links

Comment: that solution is not working for me

Comment: try `https://github.com/vnitinv/icdiff/archive/master.zip`

Comment: thanks, it is working when I am trying from setup.py 
"python setup.py install", but when I am trying to install through pip by making dist package "pip install dist/newprog.tar.gz"  it is giving above mentioned error
From log messages I can see that it is not going to mentioned url.

Comment: I'd suggest to ask the package owner to do the right thing: https://hynek.me/articles/sharing-your-labor-of-love-pypi-quick-and-dirty/