# Specify dependency url in setup.py for modules in PyPI

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, pypi

The questions I've seen here so far deal with the opposite situation, i.e. [providing a link to off-PyPI dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295968/how-to-define-dependency-links-in-setup-py-for-installing-modules-which-are-not). In my case, the dependency is published in PyPI, but the version is not up to my requirements. Here is an excerpt from my `setup.py`

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=["numpy>=1.11.0",
                      "scipy>=0.17.0",
                      "lasagne",
                      "Theano>=0.8.1",
                      "scipy>=0.17.0"],

    dependency_links=["git+https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne.git#egg=lasagne"]
)
```

I need `lasagne` to be installed from the link, while `pip` insists on installing the PyPI version.

**Edit**. I've tried doing this

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=["numpy>=1.11.0",
                      "scipy>=0.17.0",
                      "lasagne>=0.2.dev1",
                      "Theano>=0.8.1",
                      "scipy>=0.17.0"],

    dependency_links=[
        "git+https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne.git#egg=lasagne-0.2.dev1"]
)
```

This results in `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lasagne>=0.2.dev1`

**Edit2**

Actually passing the `--process-dependency-links` flag as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13587734/1005215) (thanks to  Nehal J. Wani) makes it work. How can I make this flag work by default? I don't want a user to be confused.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13587734/1005215

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani Passing the `--process-dependency-links` flag makes it work, though I want this to be the default behaviour.

Comment: `alias pip='pip --process-dependency-links'`

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani I'm speaking about the user. I can write this in the readme, but not all of us read readmes carefully before installation.

Comment: Based on this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29524177/1005215 the users will require to read the README in your project!