# Specify extras_require with pip install -e

Tags: python, git, pip

How can one manage to install extras_requires with pip when installing from a git repository ?

I know that you can do `pip install project[extra]` when the project is on pypi.
And you have to do `pip install -e git+https://github.com/user/project.git#egg=project` for a git repo but I didn't manage to find how to link these two options together.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061610/pip-install-dependency-links

Comment: my problem is not about simple dependencies but extras

Answer (score 202, accepted):

This should work, [per examples #6 and #7](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#examples)

For remote repos:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/user/project.git#egg=project[extra]
```

And this for local ones (thanks to @Kurt-Bourbaki):

```
pip install -e .[extra]
```

---

As per @Kurt-Bourbaki:

If you are using `zsh` you need to escape square brackets or use quotes:

```bash
pip install -e .\[extra\]
# or
pip install -e ".[extra]"
```

As per @Epoc:

Windows Powershell will also require quoting the brackets.

Comment: Just what I needed! This also works when you define it in requirements.txt or setup.py.

Comment: But what if `pip install -e .` is used, and not a URL?

Comment: @ankostis `pip install -e .[extra]` should work. If you're using `zsh` you need to escape square brackets: `pip install -e .\[extra\]`.

Comment: Also notice that if requirements from `setup.py` are not being installed by `pip` it may be because [you have an *egg.info folder next to setup.py](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4780)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed as well. I am just wondering, what if the git repo contains multiple packages which are not listed in setup.py explicitly, i.e. with 'find_packages' and I want to use `git+https...` to get the same installation as with `pip install -e .[extra]`? This `pip install -e git+https://github.com/user/project.git#egg=.[extra]` does not work.

Comment: On Windows, Powershell will complain about the brackets. Simply put the argument between double quotes, e.g: `pip install -e ".[extra]"`

Comment: @ankostis your answer helps if you're using `zsh`, but quotes as suggested by @Epoc also work (probably for any shell/platform). So the answer should be:
`pip install -e ".[extra]"`

Comment: The notation for git seems to be now outdated, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780980

Comment: Just to be 100% clear, the "." before the "[extra]" indicates the current directory, right?

Answer (score 44):

Important to notice: you should not have whitespaces around or within brackets. I.e. **this will work:** `-e ".[extra1,extra2]"` but **this won't:** `-e ". [extra1, extra2]"` - and even as a row in requirements.txt file, where it is not so obvious. The worst thing about it is that when you have whitespace, extras are just silently ignored.

Comment: I haven't seen this documented anywhere for multiple extras but it's a quite important tip!

Comment: @bastula you're right, it is seemingly undocumented - but at least as of time of writing it was the way it behaved.

Answer (score 17):

It may not be obvious for some users, and wasn't for me, so thought to highlight that `extra` in the following command

```
pip install -e ".[extra]"
```

needs to be replaced by the actual name of the extra requirements.

**Example:**

You add `options.extras_require` section to your `setup.cfg` as follows:

```
[options.extras_require]
  test =
    pre-commit>=2.10.1,<3.0
    pylint>=2.7.2,<3.0
    pytest>=6.2.2,<7.0
    pytest-pspec>=0.0.4,<1.0
```

Then you install the `test` extra as follows

```
pip install -e ".[test]"
```

Comment: The options.extras_require section doesn't work for me, resulting in errors. If my pyproject.toml has an options.extras_require, either it is ignored, either it errors out about invalid TOML, and Google search only gives me results about that now incorrect syntax. What do I do then?

Answer (score 5):

This also works when installing from a `whl` file so, for example, you can do:

```
pip install path/to/myapp-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl[extra1]
```

This is very far from clear from the docs, and not particularly intuitive.

Answer (score 5):

To install `project`'s extra requirements under `extra` from git, the more modern syntax is

```
python -m pip install -e "project[extra] @ git+https://github.com/user/project.git"
```

Source: in the [pip documentation Examples](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#examples), see "Install a package with extras".

Installing via the command in the current accepted answer—

```
python -m pip install -e git+https://github.com/user/project.git#egg=project[extra]
```

—will raise this warning:

> DEPRECATION: git+https://github.com/user/project.git#egg=project[extra] contains an egg fragment with a non-PEP 508 name pip 25.0 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use the req @ url syntax, and remove the egg fragment. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11617

Answer (score 0):

Using git + ssh to install packages with extras from private repositories:

```
pip install -e 'git+ssh://git@github.com/user/project.git#egg=project[extra1,extra2]'
```

Comment: There should be no space between the extras. Also, installing packages with git is already covered in the accepted answer, albeit with `https` not `ssh`. I'd say this answer would work best as an edit over the accepted one, striving to cumulate and structure the knowledge

Answer (score 0):

setup.cfg does not behave the same as requirements.txt, at the end there is an workaround for that

```py
# setup.cfg
...
[options.extras_require]
dev =
    pytest
    pytest-cov
    pylint
    coverage
    mypy
    types-requests
    custolint

ciur =
    # ciur==0.2.0
    ciur # 0.2.0

selenium =
    ada-automation.selenium-bot
...
```

```py
# setup.py

from setuptools import setup

setup()
```

To install editable

```bash
pip install \
    -e "${BITBUCKET_ORG_REPOS}/ada-automation/scraping_bot/_lib" \
    -e "${BITBUCKET_ORG_REPOS}/python-ciur" \
    -e ".[ciur,selenium,dev]"
```

Confirm that is editable

```bash
> pip list | egrep 'ciur|selenium|pytest'
ada-automation.selenium-bot 0.0.0      /Users/xxx/bitbucket.org/ada-automation/scraping_bot/_lib
ciur                        0.2.0      /Users/xxx/bitbucket.org/python-ciur
pytest                      7.4.0
pytest-cov                  4.1.0
selenium                    4.0.0
```