# How can I install a local Python package with extra components using pip?

Tags: python, pip, package, extra

`pip` supports installing extra components while installing a Python package from internet, e.g.,

```
pip install dask[all]
pip install "dask[all] @ git+https://github.com/dask/dask"
```

However, does it support installing extra components when installing from a local Python package? For example, if I have the dask Python package downloaded to local, how can I install it with specific extra components?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify extras\_require with pip install -e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239152/specify-extras-require-with-pip-install-e)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can install extras from a local package. If they're defined in the package's `setup.py` file in the `extras_require` dictionary, then you can install them with `pip install ."[extra1, extra2]"`. For example, if you have the following in your `setup.py`:

```py
extras_require={
        'docs': ["sphinx>=1.6", "sphinx_rtd_theme>=0.2.4", "sphinx-click"],
        'dev': ["pre-commit>=2.10.0"]
    },
```

you can install the `docs` and `dev` extras with `pip install ".[docs, dev]"` when you're in the directory containing `setup.py` (you'd use the path to the directory containing `setup.py` in the place of `.` otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

I've just figured it out.

```
pip3 install "dsutil[cv] @ file:///home/dclong/dsutil-0.54.1-py3-none-any.whl"
```