# setup.py dependency_links not searched for install_requires

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

This question has been asked several times around the site, but the answer frequently seems to be an omission of the `install_requires` arg.
Not the case here.

I'm trying to build a wheel that can be pip installed in a way that also installs a required package that's *not* on PyPI.

my `setup.py` includes:

```
setup(
    install_requires= ['shotgun-api3']
    dependency_links = [
        "git+https://github.com/shotgunsoftware/python-api.git@v3.0.36#egg=shotgun_api3"
    ],
    # ...
)
```

From the commandline I then run `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` to generate the `/dist/mypackage-0.1.0-py2-none-any.whl`.

Rather than upload my package to an index, I'm trying to install my package from the filesystem; so in a clean virtualenv, I then run:
`pip -v install mypackage --no-index --find-links file:///F:/RyDev/myproject/dist --process-dependency-links`.

And I get:

```
DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for shotgun-api3 (from mypackage)
```

and because I used the verbose flag, I see:

```
Collecting shotgun-api3 (from mypackage)
  0 location(s) to search for versions of shotgun-api3:
  Skipping link file:///F:/RyDev/mypackage/dist/mypackage-4.0.0-py2-none-any.whl; wrong project name (not shotgun-api3)
  Skipping link file:///F:/RyDev/mypackage/dist/mypackage-4.0.0.tar.gz; wrong project name (not shotgun-api3)
```

It's maybe worth noting:

- if I remove the `install_requires` arg from `setup.py`, `mypackage` will pip install without errors...just without the dependency.
- I can run `pip install git+https://github.com/shotgunsoftware/python-api.git@v3.0.36#egg=shotgun_api3` and it successfully installs the shotgun-api3 package.

...but for the life of me, I can't seem to get `shotgun-api3` to install ***as a dependency*** for `mypackage`.

It looks to me like ***the (git) URL I provided to dependency_links isn't being included in the list of locations***, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something around that?

Environment:

- Python 2.7.13 (cannot upgrade)
- Windows 7 (cannot switch OS)
- pip              10.0.1
- setuptools       39.2.0
- virtualenv       16.0.0
- wheel            0.31.1

Comment: If I remember correctly, `pip` expects the package name in `install_requires` to match the egg name and link in `dependency_links`, so it must be smth like `install_requires=['python-api']` and the dep link `github.com/shotgunsoftware/python-api.git@v3.0.36#egg=python-api`. It will still install package named `shotgun-api3` because the real name will be taken from the setup script.

Comment: You're right about the name match, but it looks like `shotgun_api3` really is the name.  I'd cloned the source and built the egg locally, and it generates `shotgun_api3-3.0.36-py2.7.egg`, so I'm thinking it must be something else?

Comment: ...again, the verbose output seems to indicate not that it can't find the package at the URL, but rather that it doesn't even look in the URL at all.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution for this? I am having the same issue right now:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52735269/installing-from-custom-index-setup-py

Answer (score 2):

As for your setup.py:

In [`pip` 19.0 and later](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#id146), `dependency_links` is ignored. Use the PEP 508 syntax to specify the URLs to be used by `pip`:

```
setup(
    install_requires= ['shotgun-api3 @ git+https://github.com/shotgunsoftware/python-api.git@v3.0.36#egg=shotgun_api3']
    dependency_links = [
        "git+https://github.com/shotgunsoftware/python-api.git@v3.0.36#egg=shotgun_api3"
    ],
    # ...
)
```

I've left your `dependency_links` in because nested dependencies in `pip` make use of `setuptools`, as discussed today in the comments of [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54793503/1580660).

Regarding the installation:

Since I don't have your local packages it's not possible to check if this answer solves your problem. Be sure to remove the `--process-dependency-links` part when testing it though, because that is no longer supported in the latest `pip` either.

Alternatively, to install your local package, try `pip install -e .` instead of manually compiling and specifying everything.