# Installing from custom index setup.py

Tags: python, pip, packaging, setup.py, pypi

I am the package maintainer of a package that has dependencies to packages hosted in our own pip repository.

I want these packages to also be installed when doing `pip install mypackage`.

```
setup(
  name='mypackage',
  version='1.1.2',
  description='My awesome package',
  dependency_links=[
    'http://www.myrepo.se/packages/mydep1/',
    'http://www.myrepo.se/packages/mydep2/'
  ]
  install_requires=[
    'mydep1==1.0.0',
    'mydep2==5.6.7'
  ]
)
```

The folder structure in the repo is the following:

```
packages/
  mydep1/
    mydep1-1.0.0.tar.gz
  mydep2/
    mydep2-5.5.1.tar.gz
    mydep2-5.6.7.tar.gz
```

All according to the accepted answer on this question [Using an extra python package index url with setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443583/using-an-extra-python-package-index-url-with-setup-py)

However, this does not work. I get the error:

```
Collecting mydep1 (from mypackage==1.1.2)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mydep1 (from mypackage==1.1.2) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mydep1 (from mypackage==1.1.2)
```

When I have added an extra index url to my requirements.txt before doing it this was I had to add the url as a trusted host. Is that relevant? Also I am using python 3.5.3

EDIT: 
I activated verbose output from pip and it is not even trying to find the package from my repo.

```
1 location(s) to search for versions of mydep1:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/mydep1/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/mydep1/
  ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip ignores dependency\_links in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518499/pip-ignores-dependency-links-in-setup-py)

Comment: Yes. It is a duplicate in that the solution was the same. It is also not a duplicate since I was trying to install from a custom pypi repo and he was trying to install from GitHub. Also, even though I searched I didn't find it until after I posted my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `pip` is not processing the dependency links unless you explicitly tell it to (which unfortunately means that all consumers of mypackage must know to do so).

```
pip install --process-dependency-links mypackage
```

Since `mypackage` is also hosted by the same repository it means that a consumers `requirements.txt` must look like

```
--trusted-host http://www.myrepo.se/
--extra-index-url http://www.myrepo.se/packages
--process-dependency-links

mypackage==1.1.2
```

Comment: The `--process-dependency-links` option is no longer supported in `pip` v 19.0.3. I have exactly the issue stated here, but without this option am unsure how to proceed?

Comment: @Gabriel, use the PEP 508 syntax described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54793503/1580660) to get `pip` 19.0 to play nicely with URLs: `install_requires = ['package @ https://url/to/package.tar#egg=package']`.

Just keep in mind that PyPI [will retire this functionality somewhere the future](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#id188).