# pip install package still not following dependency links

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm having serious trouble with using setup.py to pip install my package which also has dependency links. I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061610/pip-install-dependency-links) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472430/how-can-i-make-setuptools-install-a-package-thats-not-on-pypi) thoroughly and none of the answers including the accepted ones help.

Here is the [setup.py](https://gist.github.com/jmerkow/c16c8f894cdcc762f0f5280fc850afbc) for the package trying to install.
Basically, it reads the requirements.txt to fill install_requires and dependency_links, most of the rest of the code is boilerplate from cookie-cutter.  requirements.txt has a private github repo in it which is causing the issues. e.g. `git+https://${GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN}@github.com/jmerkow/pripy.git#egg=pripy`

When I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` everything works great, it installs the private repository.  However, if I try to install using `pip install . --process-dependency-links`, I get this error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pripy (from mypackage==<sha>) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pripy (from mypackage==<sha>)
```

If I take off the `#egg=xxx` from the link in requirements, the private repo package is completely ignored by `pip install .` but not by `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

I have confirmed that `dependency_links` contains `'git+https://<actual-token>@github.com/jmerkow/pripy.git#egg=pripy'` and that `install_requires` includes `'pripy'`

How do you get setup to properly Is this a problem with the sub-package? `setup.py` in that repo is done pretty much the same, except there are no private links.

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, this always happens.  I put in all the work to the question, then I figure it out myself.

The issue is two things, first, all dependeny_links need to have a version, second to pull the version from the requirements file properly you need to do some magic on the string.

Comparing to the above setup.py, I changes the way requirements are added to the two lists (updated [here](https://gist.github.com/jmerkow/c16c8f894cdcc762f0f5280fc850afbc#file-setup-py-fixed)). Then add the version to `#egg=xxx` on the link e.g.
`git+https://${GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN}@github.com/jmerkow/pripy.git#egg=pripy-0`.

Now setup.py will parse that file, take the egg version info, convert it to a pip version (basically replace the first `'-'` with an `'=='`) for the install_requires, and you're good to go.