# Heroku Django setup install_requires from github

Tags: django, heroku, pip

I have a heroku project that is trying to install a [Django reusable app](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.x/intro/reusable-apps.html) using `pip install -r requirements.txt` (it's not the exact command from the official `heroku/python` buildpack, but it's basically doing that).

The problem is that my Django reusable app has a requirement itself, from a Github public repository.

A few answers in [pip install dependency links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061610/pip-install-dependency-links) point to:

- The dependency-links syntax [being not compatible with pip 19](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/)
- The new syntax (i.e. `package @ git+protocol://...`) of course not being compatible with older versions of pip.

My Django project can be deployed in different ways: Heroku, local, Docker (dev and prod). Most of these deployment methods have the latest version of pip.

Heroku's python buildpack has [Pip 9.0.2](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/93a620e6edacde750d32af6e3c8c3ad5e6800a40/bin/compile#L65)

My other deployment methods have Pip 19, so they have incompatibilities in the way they read requirements, and I can't have a method that works for both.

For older versions of pip, I do in my `setup.py`:

```
setup(
# [...]
install_requires=[
        "my_package == x.y.z"
    ],
    dependency_links=["git+https://github.com/account/package/tarball/master#egg=my_package-x.y.z"]
)
```

Whereas for Pip 19, I do:

```
setup(
# [...]
install_requires=[
        "my_package @ git+https://github.com/company/package.git"
    ],
)
```

I tried forking the repo and just increasing the version to pip's latest version. It does work, except for errors in [pip-diff](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/vendor/pip-pop/pip-diff), which don't seem to have an effect on the build.

Interesting to note too is that since the buildpack has a cache system, you generally notice this problem only once until you require a newer version of a library. But it's a problem with review apps for example.

So what is the solution here? I could:

1. Downgrade all other deployment methods to an older version of pip that works with dependency links, including all my local dev setups
2. Use a forked version of heroku's python buildpack, with updated pip (pip-diff needs to be fixed though)
3. Remove dependencies from github and add those dependencies at the project repo level instead of the reusable app level.
4. Submit a PR to the official repo so that pip can get upgraded

That's all I can think of. Solutions 1. and 2. are really bad IMHO, 3. is even worse, and 4. can take time, which I can't really afford.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The *pip* notation is not the same as the the *setuptools* notation. There is no immediate reason to change the setup script. The `install_requires` and `dependency_links` seem fine in the first version, and probably actually are if it used to work.

Now, it is true that the newer version of *pip* do not take the `dependency_links` of *setuptools* into account at all. So these custom dependency links can be added to a `requirements.txt` file instead (with the *pip* notation of course).

Additionally you could choose to entirely remove the `dependency_links` argument in the setup script to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Do you mean adding it to the `requirements.txt` of the package being added, or to the `requirements.txt` of the project importing the package? because if it's the latter, it's not a good solution IMHO

Comment: From my (and the _pip_ maintainers as well, I think) point of view, the reasoning is: if I use _pip_ to install Python packages and their dependencies, **I assume that they will all be downloaded from PyPI which is a hosting service that I trust**, but I am certainly not OK if a dependency breaches this contract and requires code from a different host. That's why the _dependency links_ should only be enforced by the one who actually triggers the installation, i.e. `requirements.txt` of the application. **Libraries only need to clearly document if they need dependencies that are not on PyPI**.

Comment: OK, I understand. I'll see if that works with my colleagues. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the right answer, but I used [this workaround](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5898#issuecomment-494185129)

So basically in my `setup.py` I add a function and call it:

```
def install_github_package(github_url):
    try:
        import github_url
        # ... do some version checking ...
    except (ModuleNotFoundError, ImportError):
        if '--user' in sys.argv:
            subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade',
                            '--user', github_url], check=False)
        else:
            subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade',
                            github_url], check=False)

install_github_package("git+https://github.com/company/package.git")
```

Comment: If it works for your use case, then go for it. But if you use pip and most importantly if you already have a `requirements.txt` file for your application anyway, then placing the custom links for the dependencies in this file is probably a much better solution.

Comment: I tried using the way you told me to, I forgot to mention I use `pip-tools`, and I'm having trouble doing a `pip-compile` if I follow what you said, i.e.:

- keep install_requires and dependency_links
- add my dependency in `requirements.in`
- try to run `pip-compile`

What should I do in this case? manually add a line to the file generated by `pip-compile`?

Comment: I don't know _pip-tools_, can't help much. But from quickly looking at its _README_, I'd say add the custom _git_ dependency link to the `requirements.in`, yes. Or you may have to then edit `requirements.txt` manually afterwards.

Comment: yeah, does not work by putting it in the `.in`... I guess I have to add it afterwards... That's my problem with all this, it seems not totally compatible with the pip ecosystem, but it's my opinion only.

Comment: Surprised it doesn't work. If I were you, I would start with a fresh question specifically focused on _pip-compile_, or directly ask in their issue tracker.

Comment: Yes I will do that, thanks for the explanation on the reasoning on external dependencies